# Use of unresolved identifier 'zombies'

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, append, skspritenode

I am making a zombie apocalypse-style cheese game and I am having trouble knowing where/how to declare zombies. I thought that since I had them made in my Gamescene.sks file with each the name 'zombie,' then they would be declared like that. I am trying to make the zombies(which I made 4 in the .sks file) chase the player(which I also set up the .sks file and coded in the upper lines of code.)

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as? SKSpriteNode

    for child in self.children{
        if child.name == "zombie"{
            if let child = child as? SKSpriteNode {
                zombies.append(child)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is my first app that I am trying to make using .sks files.

Comment: It is really unclear whether or not you are asking a question here. Is there an error? are the zombies not being found and put in your array? what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

After a while of trying, I found out that my .sks and .swift files were not communicating and I had to set up the view.

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView?
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
```